# How to execute two transactions concurrently in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, transactions

I want to execute concurrently two transactions in **Postgresql** and that's what I've got

```
--The first transaction should modify the age of Paul
BEGIN;
DECLARE newage INTEGER;
--the original age of Paul is 32
newage := Select age FROM COMPANY WHERE name = Paul;
newage := newage+10;
update company set age := Sage where name = Paul;
commit;


--The second Transaction shows all information about Paul including his age
Begin
select * from company where name = 'Paul';
commit;
```

Both parts were written in the same SQL Editor. My first problem is that it doesn't compile, I obtain the message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INTEGER"
LINE 2: DECLARE newage INTEGER;
```

How can I improve my code to execute it? Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're mixing plpgsql and sql. Your first transactions isn't valid SQL, but it looks like plpgsql. But it only looks like it, it's also not valid plpgsql. So what are you looking for?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm using PgAdmin and I want to run 2 transactions concurrently. Apart from the syntax-failure to declare the variable. Is it correct if I execute them on the same SQL Editor Window? I mean "Begin; ...commit;" for the 1th transaction and "Begin; ...commit;" for the second transaction?

Answer (score 0):

1. In PostgreSQL you cannot declare variables in SQL, but you can do it in [`pl/pgsql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-declarations.html)
2. [DECLARE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-declare.html) keyword creates a cursor, not a variable.
3. Use [SELECT INTO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-selectinto.html) to set value to the `newage`
4. Use [DO](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-do.html) to execute pl/pgsql. It will be executed in a single transaction.

So the result query looks like:

```
DO $$ DECLARE
    newage INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT age INTO newage FROM companey WHERE name = 'Paul';
    newage := newage+10;
    UPDATE company SET age = newage where name = 'Paul';
END $$:
```